# What is the mechanism behind sympathic effusion of serous cavities due to nearby abscess?

Tags: physiology, medicine

Patient with left perinephric abcess which does not ruptured have reduced breath sound that is mostly due to plural effusion revealed by CT scan which was sterile. I found this called sympathetic effusion , Why it named as this and what is the mechanism behind it ?

Answer (score 2):

The left perinephric space is adjacent to the left subpleural space so inflammation can spread from the former to the latter.

Diaphragmatic inflammation then results in a left exudative sterile pleural effusion. It's called sympathetic since it's not infective.

https://radiopaedia.org/articles/perirenal-space

https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/1979032-clinical#b4